# How to make a range slider with spefic bar color

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, range

I would like to write a range slider in javascript with spefic bar color that does not depend on the position of the selector.
How can I do it ?

My inspiration is the following [website](https://smartasset.com/mortgage/rent-vs-buy)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/LP5XA/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider
{
    background-color:red;
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider(
    {
        slide:function(event, ui){
            //This is what the original code for this example looks like.
            //It's for changing the white/red area when the slider moves.
            //var w = $(ui.handle).css("left");
            //$(this).css("background-size",w);

            //Notice how when you set the "w" value to a static value it
            //will keep the white/red space static as well?  So you can 
            //change the colored space with whatever logic you want to use.
            $(this).css("background-size",50);
        }   
    });
});
```

Do whatever you want to do involving changing the width and color of the background.  It seems like the website with your example does it based off a calculation done on the threshold between renting and buying and when one becomes ideal over another.

Comment: can we do it the same based on this library ?http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_advanced.html